# How to plot several seaborn heatmaps in a single figure?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn, heatmap

I have generated a sns heatmap (ClusterGrid object) using [scVelo](https://scvelo.readthedocs.io/scvelo.pl.heatmap.html#scvelo.pl.heatmap), but how does one fit serval such objects into a single figure in matplotlib?

I've tired many options (and of course attempted any suggestion I could find on StackOverflow :) but nothing seems to work. I can export to png and reload the data, but that reduces the quality of the images.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is not an optimal solution, but this is what I was able to come up with.. saved the images as PNG files and then reload them as subplots

```
plt.figure(figsize=(30, 15))
plt.suptitle("title", fontsize=22)

plt.subplot(133)
plt.imshow(mpimg.imread('./figures/heatmap_2.png',format="png"))
plt.title("expression")
plt.grid(None) 
plt.axis('off')

plt.subplot(132)
plt.imshow(mpimg.imread('./figures/heatmap_1.png'), format="png"))
plt.grid(None) 
plt.axis('off')

plt.subplot(131)
plt.imshow(mpimg.imread('./figures/3.png',format="png"))
#plt.grid(None) 
plt.grid(None) 
plt.axis('off')

plt.show()
```